# Confusing behavior when assigning to the for loop variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I am intrigued why the following Python code outputs numbers 10..29 (with step 1). Tested with both Python 2.7 and 3.

```
for i in range(20):
    i += 10
    print(i)
```

So `i += 10` is executed, but executed only once despite it is in the loop. That's a very confusing behavior.

Why does Python behave this confusing way?

Comment: Why would you do such a thing?

Comment: Add another `print()` before `i+=10`.

Comment: I wouldn’t want to mess around like that in production code, but it can be educational to try things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `i += 10` is executed each time, but does not affect the value
of `i` at the beginning of the loop.

```
for i in range(20):
    # generator range(20) assigns numbers from 0 to 19 to i

    i += 10
    # i is now 10 to 29; generator not affected

    print(i)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that `range` returns a generator in Python 3, but returns a list in Python 2. Same result, though.

Answer (score 2):

One way to understand how this works is to write the for loop as an equivalent while loop:

```
it = iter(range(20))
while(True):
    i = next(it)
    i += 10
    print(i)
```

Note that `i` is reassigned a value from the iterable on each iteration of the loop. Even though the value of `i` is changed with `i += 10`, it is changed back to the loop counter at the beginning of each repetition.

(Note: `i = next(it)` will thrown an exception after the iterable is exhausted. To avoid clutter, I did not add the exception handling here that will make this technically correct.)